# SQL Server UPDATING one table from values from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update values from one table to another in SQL Server. I have 2 tables: tblBus and tblRB_ID.

```
create table tblBus
(
    bus varchar (10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    rb_id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblRB_ID(rb_id2),
    roadside_bottom varchar (20)
);
```

| Bus | rb_id | roadside_bottom |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | NULL | NULL |
| 1001 | NULL | NULL |

Here is tblRB_ID:

```
create table tblRB_ID
(
    rb_id2 int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    contract_id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblContracts(contract_id),
    rb_name varchar (20)
    CONSTRAINT rb_pass CHECK
    (
        rb_name IN ('King', 'Super King', 'Kong', 'Half Side')
    )
);
```

| rb_id2 | contract_id | roadside_bottom |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 1 | King |
| 9 | 2 | Super King |

I tried to update the values using this, but I just get an error saying "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'RIGHT'".

```
UPDATE tblBus
RIGHT JOIN tblRB_ID
ON tblBus.rb_id = tblRB_ID.rb_id2,
   tblBus.roadside_bottom = tblRB_ID.rb_name;
SET tblBus.rb_id = tblRB_ID.rb_id2,
   tblBus.roadside_bottom = tblRB_ID.rb_name;
```

I want to tblBus to updated with the information from tblRB_ID. I want both records in tblRB_ID to be into tblBus, and any subsequent record that I put into tblRB_ID. I want it to look like this:

| Bus | rb_id | roadside_bottom |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 8 | King |
| 1001 | 9 | Super King |

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at the [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax) and the [Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#UpdateExamples) (such as [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#l-specifying-a-table-alias-as-the-target-object)) in the documentation, and you'll see your `UPDATE` is quite malformed. The `JOIN`s are *before* the `SET` and you are completely missing a `FROM`.

Answer (score 2):

the syntax you are using is different. the update syntax is like below

```
UPDATE <Table Alias>
SET
    <Column to be updated> = <Column from which you need to update>
    FROM TableA a
        INNER JOIN TableB B
            ON A.<Column Name> = B.<ColumnName>
```

So your query should actually be like

```
UPDATE tblBus
SET tblBus.rb_id = tblRB_ID.rb_id2,
   tblBus.roadside_bottom = tblRB_ID.rb_name
  FROM tblBus
        JOIN tblRB_ID -- Inner join is recommended so that the non-matching rows are not updated with NULL
            ON tblBus.rb_id = tblRB_ID.rb_id2
                AND tblBus.roadside_bottom = tblRB_ID.rb_name;
```

Comment: Would this also update the two values that I have and any subsequent records I put in tblRB_ID? I tried using this, but I end up getting "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'".

Comment: @LongLouis there was a comma just before the AND, removed that now

Comment: Thank you, but it seems that it's not changing the values on tblBus. I did put INNER join and removed the comma.

Comment: Just make sure that the join columns do have matching values.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the information. How about if I want to update null values on tblBus from values from tblRB_ID? If not Inner Join, right join?

Comment: Use LEFT JOIN instaed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237205/discussion-between-longlouis-and-jayasurya-satheesh).